# Create mix CDs from MP3 files

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, batch-file, cygwin

How would you write a script (preferably for the Windows commandline) that:

- Examines thousands of MP3 files stored on a single drive (e.g., `G:\`)
- Randomizes the collection
- Populates a series of directories up to 650MB worth of songs (without exceeding 650MB)
- Every song is shucked exactly once
- (Optional) The directory size comes as close as possible to 650MB

The `DIR`, `COPY`, and `XCOPY` commands have no explicit file size switches.

A few Google searches have come up with:

- [File size condition in DOS](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/copy-file-on-filesize-condition-dos/13911.html)
- Cygwin and UWIN
- [DOS File sizes](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1383551)

It would be ideal if UNIX-like environments can be avoided.

My question, then: How do you compare file (or directory) sizes using the Windows commandline?

Comment: Why do you need it to leverage DOS?

Comment: Windows XP Pro is the environment. DOS is not necessary if there is a Windows tool that can do the same task. Also, would this be a better question for serverfault?

Comment: WinXP Pro does not even have DOS on it

Comment: I guess by saying DOS Dave means Windows command interpreter (cmd).

Comment: @d03boy: when people say "DOS" these days, they're normally referring to the Windows non-graphical command shell.  It's just easier.

Comment: I'm old school. ;-)

Comment: I am told iTunes will do this.

Comment: I know what he meant but I figured I'd bring that up anyway since this is a learning site and there should be correct information here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes has such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript WSH script. See [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(VS.85).aspx).

```
var WShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

VB is *evil*.

Comment: How could this be integrated into a working shell script?

Comment: You can use GetFolder and GetFile to iterate through folders and get the file information. The GetFolder page has a great example, and the File object returned by GetFile has a size attribute. after you selected your files you can use the fso.CopyFile method to copy the selected files.

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of a "unix-like environment"? Does a language like Tcl or Python fall into that category? Such programming languages are perfect for tasks like this, with built-in features for scanning directories, getting file sizes, moving files, etc.

Don't hamstring yourself by using a limited language like the windows batch language. Pick a real programming language that has a native port to windows and you're  job will likely be much easier.

Comment: Was just looking to create a simple script. I could do it in bash in about 30 minutes. The problem is I want to hand off the program to a friend (a one-time project). Python is a great idea.